# An int weighs more then 32 bits on my ram for some reason

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, memory

Ok so I was curious to see if an int actually weights 4 bytes on my ram.
so i made 1,000,000 ints with this code.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 1000000;++i)   
    int *as= new int;
```

Before I execute this line of code I put a breakpoint right before to see how much headover i'm starting with.
there is almost no headover, my program starts with 750 kb.

But after I finish the loop the program uses 32,000 kb when its supose to be 4,000 kb if an int weighs 32 bits.
another thing worth mentioning is that I am using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>altk + delete</kbd> method to check out how much space my program is taking from the ram and i'm running it on visual c++ 2010 express.

I am also positive that an int on my pc is 32 bits and not 64 not that it matters anyways because even if it were to be 64 and not 32 it should of been 8,000 kb and not 32,000 kb.
so maybe you can try to do this on your pc and tell me if you have the same results.

If you know where I went wrong please tell me.

Comment: In addition to the possibility of `int` being > than 4 bytes, the heap is not a linear data structure, so it may have allocated more memory than is actually occupied at any one particular moment, in addition to the bookkeeping info the implementation does for each allocation.

Comment: really how does this work exactly

Comment: Won't your program will also consume more memory if it is built in debug mode?

Comment: Now try allocating a single array of a million ints, or ten arrays of a hundred thousand ints each, and compare.

Comment: Yikes...  Talk about heap overhead...  Why didn't you just go `int *chunk = new int[1000000];`?

Answer (score 6):

4-byte chunks of memory are too small to be worth managing. There are also possible performance penalties associated with giving potentially unrelated chunks of code objects that share a cache line.

Typical memory managers have a minimum chunk size of somewhere between 16 and 256 bytes. Also, some overhead is typically needed to track the fact that a chunk of a particular size has been allocated.

Comment: Memory managers may have different heaps based on sizes.  This would reduce memory fragmentation.  A technique often used in embedded systems.

Answer (score 3):

Memory managers have some overhead to keep track of the different blocks. They may also allocate extra bits to help discover buffer overflows. Some have a minimum size block that they will allocate.

Comment: hmm i didn't know that do you have a good article where i can learn memory manegment from?

Comment: @user1680034, I don't know many of the details myself. These are just tidbits I've picked up over time.

Comment: What about data alignment (padding)? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Answer (score 2):

There's some overhead associated with heap allocation, because each block of memory the heap manager gives away has some extra information associated to it (e.g. its size).

Also, normally the heap manager doesn't provide such small blocks, because almost no one asks for single `int`s from the heap (the aforementioned extra bookkepping, among the other things, makes such small allocations a bad idea); so, each `int` you get will probably be the smallest chunk of memory the heap manages, several times bigger than an `int`.

Comment: "almost no one asks for single ints from the heap" - you don't work on the same codebase that I do, obviously. Some people are just clueless.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating integer pointers on the heap not the stack.

I see 4 bytes (32-bit) per int allocated, but also 8 bytes (64-bit) for each pointer and allocation overhead to the memory allocation.